# deck.gl - is it possible to increase the on click radius?

Tags: deck.gl

I want to add actions for when the user clicks on an object from a Paths layers. I notice that I really need to click in the middle of each path for this to happen. Is it somehow possible to increase that radius so when the user clicks even just a bit near that object the on-click action would trigger? Couldn't find such property for any layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pickingRadius`, [check this out](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/deck#pickingradius).

You should be able to apply that on Deck instance.

**With React:**

```
<DeckGL
  ...otherProps
  pickingRadius={10}
>
```

**With vanilla JS:**

```
const deckgl = new Deck({
  ...otherProps,
  pickingRadius: 10
});
```